# $http call to get data to other $http call in other file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, synchronization, angular-services

I want to read URL from one json file and feed URL to other javascript file having $http GET request to execute that URL. I am using one service in another service file for getting data. Whenever I run it, it says **undefined** in **url:** property of **bannerslides** function.

**common.js:**

```
 (function() {
    angular.module('siteModule')
        .service('loggerService', function($http, $q) {
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/config/config.json').then(function(data) {
                deffered.resolve(data);
            });
            this.getPlayers = function() {
                return deffered.promise;
            }
        })
})();
```

**siteService.js:**

```
(function() {
  var confUrl;
  angular.module('siteModule')
    .service('siteService', function($http, $q, loggerService) {
      this.bannerSlides = function() {
        loggerService.getPlayers().then(function(data) {
          confUrl = data.data.baseUrl + data.data.urls.site;
          console.log("GOTURL", confUrl);
          //move your return statement here 
          return $http({
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: confUrl
          })
        });
      }
    })
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicate that siteService.bannerSlides is not recognised as a promise. When i look at your code, you just return the actual value. Then what you need is callback in siteService.bannerSlides.

```
Error code is angular.js:14324 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

**siteController.js**

```
 // modify this to accept callback instead of using then
 siteService.bannerSlides(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
 })
```

**siteService.js**

```
 this.bannerSlides = function(callback) {
     loggerService.getPlayers().then(function(data) {
     confUrl = data.data.baseUrl + data.data.urls.site;
     console.log("GOTURL", confUrl);

     //move your return statement here 
     $http({
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: confUrl
     }).then(function (response) {
           // inspect/modify the received data and pass it onward
           //console.log("MAke url", confUrl);

         // add this
         return callback(response.data);
       }, function (error) {
       // inspect/modify the data and throw a new error or return data
         throw error;
       });
    }); //loggerService
  }
```

Comment: It's not working please look into plnkr , Error code is angular.js:14324 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
http://plnkr.co/edit/qKO1ODM6YYHn1dmnfnbt?p=preview

Comment: Oh. i know what actual problem is. You miss callback function. Let me update my answer.

Comment: No man, its not working , go to plunkr code I have mentioned above, do the changes in plunkr code and check whether it is working

Comment: Oh. I just forgot to remove return $http and just only return callback(response.data), please refer to updated answer.  You know your http.get just gave timeout error and the callback don't run if then is not executed. If you put the callback(data) under console.log("GOTURL", confUrl) it will execute.

Comment: You did it dude :)

Comment: Glad that it help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example on plunker/jsfiddle ?

You don't have to use deferred object and $q service with $http.

In loggerService you can just do

```
this.getPlayers = function() {
    return $http.get('/config/config.json').then(function(data) {
        return data;
    });
}
```

Also, if you want to use then inside of siteController.js
   **siteService.bannerSlides().then**
you are supposed to do a return inside bannerSlides functions, so it returns $http / promise.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/qKO1ODM6YYHn1dmnfnbt?p=preview

Error code is 
**angular.js:14324 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

Answer (score -1):

On Jquery simple http `GET` [jquery.getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson)

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```